# Getting three random dates from each hour

Tags: mysql, random

The title doesn't actually fully describes the problem, that is: I have a table with dates -

```
 1. 2011-07-01 13:01:48
 2. 2011-07-01 13:09:36 
 3. 2011-07-01 13:21:24
 4. 2011-07-01 13:35:12
 5. 2011-07-01 13:49:23
 6. 2011-07-01 13:57:47
 7. 2011-07-01 14:05:12
 8. 2011-07-01 14:12:45
 9. 2011-07-01 14:31:48
 10. 2011-07-01 14:47:31
```

and so on. What I need is to get three random dates of each hour, for example:

```
 1. 2011-07-01 13:01:48
 2. 2011-07-01 13:21:24
 3. 2011-07-01 13:49:23
 4. 2011-07-01 14:05:12
 5. 2011-07-01 14:12:45
 6. 2011-07-01 14:47:31
```

How can I do it in mysql?

Comment: Get a random selection from the date table within your date range. Put the results into a temp table and then select a random selection between those results.  Then go back and and accept some answers on this site.

Comment: are you using PHP or language ?

Comment: George, I had this idea but failed to implement it. Would you show the query?

Comment: @Sourav: He's using MySQL. It says so in the question.

Comment: Sourav, I need this in pure mysql.

Comment: i dont think you can do that in single query.

Comment: @Zapadlo How many rows do you usually have in one hour?

Comment: By pure mysql you rule out stored procedures?

Comment: @Karolis, it might be 10 rows and it might be 1000 rows.

Comment: @Clodoaldo, I don't rule them out, but it would be great if I can get it done without them. Anyway, if you know how to do it with stored procedured - tell me how, please. I'm just not good at this subject.

Comment: Oh, you already did :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work quite well if you have **statistically enough** rows per hour:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from yourtable
    order by rand()
)
group by date(yourdate), hour(yourdate), floor(rand()*3)
```

Comment: What do you mean by statistically enough? When there are a lot of rows per hour? I tried on 5 rows per hour -- and I got all of them in my result set :) Anyway, nice query, thanks :) But what does ORDER BY RAND() mean? And how the limit of three random rows is supposed to be achieved?

Comment: @Zapadlo sorry, there was a little bug. Fixed.

Comment: Would you please explain how all this magic works? The query actuallu looks a bit weird with all these ORDER BY RAND() and GROUP BY FLOOR(RAND() * 3) :)

Comment: `order by rand()` shuffles all the rows for to get equal mathematical probability for every row. `floor(rand()*3)` is a random integer in set (0-2). So, grouping by this value means that we get no more that 3 unique rows for every date/hour. The downside of this method is that if you have very few rows (for instance 4 rows) per hour then in some cases you may get less than 3 rows. But this will not always happen.

Comment: But why when I write this:

select * from myTable t
group by date(t.date), hour(t.date), 2

I get the error: "Unknown column 2 in group by statement"? The table really has only one column. When I put 0 instead of 2 -- the same error. It only works with 1, but why it works with floor(rand()*3) either, though it results in the same values: 0, 1, 2?

Comment: @Zapadlo Because direct value in group by clause means the number of column rather than value itself. As a work around you may try `cast(2 as signed)` or just try to add quotes `'2'` or something similar. But without random value you will get only one row per date/hour.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table dates (`date` datetime);
insert into dates (`date`) values
('2011-07-11 06:05:02'),
('2011-07-11 06:15:02'),
('2011-07-11 06:45:02'),
('2011-07-11 06:55:02'),
('2011-07-11 06:56:02'),
('2011-07-11 08:05:02'),
('2011-07-11 08:07:02'),
('2011-07-11 08:09:02'),
('2011-07-11 08:11:02'),
('2011-07-11 08:40:02'),
('2011-07-11 09:05:02'),
('2011-07-11 11:10:02'),
('2011-07-11 11:11:02'),
('2011-07-11 11:55:02')
;

set @i := 0;
set @d := '';
select `date`
from (
    select  
        case 
            when @d != date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H') 
            then @i := 0
            else @i := @i + 1
        end as i,
        case
            when @d != date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H') 
            then @d := date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
        end as d,
        case when @i < 3 then `date` else null end as `date`
    from (
        select `date`
        from dates
        order by date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), rand()
    ) ss
) sw
where `date` is not null
order by `date`
;
```

Comment: I made a refactoring eliminating one nested query.

Answer (score 1):

if data set is not large -- if your data set is large then you should not use some random algorithm on the data set anyway, then you can use the following simple query:

```
select * from t order by rand() limit 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is write the query to select everything that you need, then store the results in either an array or a temporary table. If you use a temporary table, add a column for index, and when you insert your data into the temporary table, write the value into the index column as well.  Then out of that array or temporary table, query for the records associated with what ever index is generated by the random number generator.